# What variable type do I use in mysql for saving checkbox values?

Tags: mysql, checkbox

For example I have a checkbox beside the persons name on their profile settings page with the option to make this visible to the public or not.
    Visible?

In my database I will have a variable called first_name_visible. what type should it be? Checkboxes return a the value (in this case "1") if checked, and null if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does have BOOL and BOOLEAN data types, but they are synonymous with INT(1). So this is the type you would use with the possible values 0,1, or NULL.

1 would be true (checked).
0 would be false.
NULL should be considered NULL - no value entered. I would avoid using NULL to represent false. This allows you to better check your inputs and data integrity. In most cases I would set BOOLEAN columns to NOT NULL.

Comment: Should I use a default value of 1 then, since by default I want these things to be visible?

Comment: So in php will I have to check if the checkbox is checked, and if it isn't, make sure the value is set to 0 instead of null? Is this necessary?

Comment: NULL should NOT represent false. NULL means NO VALUE. There's a big difference. It's a pretty simple check after all. `$checked = ($_POST['checkbox']) ? 1 : 0; sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ($checked);` [NB. Code just meant to illustrate the ease, there's better ways to right this obviously.

Personally I wouldn't have my app depend on database defaults for inserting values. What if the defaults change? OTOH I wouldn't have my database depend on the app, thus defaults. ;)

Comment: What would you suggest I do :P Right now I have them set to booleans with some of default 0 and some default 1. When the page loads up it will check/uncheck depending on what's in the database.

Comment: I'd suggest you set a default in your database if a default is necessary. I'd suggest your forms always submit a value, whether 0 or 1. I'd suggest you always try to record the submitted value. I've learned to envision frontends and backends as separate systems and not a single system, because that's what they really are, so it's beside not to have one depend on settings from another.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean type is the best one for this case, 1 being true and null being false

Comment: can a boolean hold a null?